# Could anyone help me with mouse speed please?

Tags: 16.04, mouse, touchpad, elantech

**My mouse is way too fast and it really bugs me. I was looking for a solution but none of them worked for me.**

**"xinput --list --short" output:**

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer               id=2   [master pointer (3)]
⎜ ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer       id=4   [slave pointer (2)]
⎜ ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad         id=12  [slave pointer (2)]
```

**"xinput --list-props"ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"" output:**

```
Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad': 
        Device Enabled (139): 1 
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000 
        libinput Tapping Enabled (273): 0 
        libinput Tapping Enabled Default (274): 0 
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled (275): 1 
        libinput Tapping Drag Enabled Default (276): 1 
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled (277): 0 
        libinput Tapping Drag Lock Enabled Default (278): 0 
        libinput Accel Speed (279): 0.000000 
        libinput Accel Speed Default (280): 0.000000 
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (281): 0 
        libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (282): 0 
        libinput Send Events Modes Available (257): 1, 1 
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (258): 0, 0 
        libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (259): 0, 0 
        libinput Left Handed Enabled (283): 0 
        libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (284): 0 
        libinput Scroll Methods Available (285): 1, 1, 0 
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled (286): 1, 0, 0 
        libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (287): 1, 0, 0 
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled (288): 0 
        libinput Disable While Typing Enabled Default (289): 1 
        Device Node (260):     "/dev/input/event6" 
        Device Product ID (261): 2, 14 
        libinput Drag Lock Buttons (290): <no items> 
        libinput Horizonal Scroll Enabled (262): 1
```

**I tried to mess around with "xset m" but it doesn't do anything.**

Edit: Lenovo z50-70

Comment: Have you tried going to System Settings and opening Mouse and Trackpad, and change pointer speed?

Comment: Still is an answer to be able to fix his problem. He asked how to fix his mouse being too fast. This is an easy solution.

Comment: Of course, this was the first thing to try, but moving the "Pointer speed" doesn't do anything..

Comment: Your wall of text is nearly impossible to read. It will take many minutes to clean it up.

Comment: Sorry @WinEunuuchs2Unix , now It's cleaned up

Comment: I was cleaning it up at the same time, not sure which version will be saved.

Comment: Can you update your question with your laptop make and model? (preferably not with bold letters).